# how to use class files inside a jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm using **eclipse**, the jar files locate in ~/zmx/alg4/algs4.jar, the class file I need is algs4.jar/A.class. my project exists in ~/workspace/test. the jar file are already in **Referenced Libraries**, how can I use the class file in my project? I've already tried:

```
import A; 
private A variable = new A();
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: what is the package that reside A?

Comment: It should work if you have algs4.jar in your references libraries.

Comment: @Iakshman no package in A, only class files.

Comment: @Ankit I've already done Add External JARS

Comment: Is it a library available. Can you give the link to the library you want to use.

Comment: @Ankit It's an assignment from a online course, http://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/percolation.html algs4.jar in 4th line.

Comment: There is no class named A in this jar file. A jar file is a zip file. Unzip it, and you'll see which class files are in this jar. Also, note that putting classes in the defult package is a very bad practice. Shame should be on princeton to do that. And shame on them to put source files in the same jar as class files as well.

Comment: @JBNizet A is an example name, what I need to use is the WeightedQuickUnionUF class, but import WeightedQuickUnionUF; doesn't work.

Comment: Is your class in the default package? If not, then unfortunately, it will have to be, because classes in the default package can't be imported, and Princeton decided to put all their classes in the default package. So the only way for your class to used the princeton classes is to also put them in the default package.

Comment: @JBNizet No, I create a package for my class, and...it works to put it in the default package, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can’t use classes in the default package from a named package: ["[import] require a compile-time error on any attempt to import a type in an unnamed package"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5). You may want to access it via reflection (see below), or repackage your library algs4.jar if you have the source code.

```
 Class.forName("SomeClass").getMethod("someMethod").invoke(null);
```